# std::lock_guard does not lock the mutex as expected

Tags: c++, mutex, stdmutex

In the following example, func should hang because it attempts to get a lock after main:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <mutex>

std::mutex myMutex;

void func(void)
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(myMutex);
    std::printf("WTF somehow got lock!!!\n"); 
}


int main()
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(myMutex);
    // Mutex is locked here.

    func();
}
```

Yet, when I run it func somehow gets the lock. Why is my C++ not working? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to lock a `std::mutex` in a given thread that is already locked by the same thread has undefined behavior.

One can use `std::recursive_mutex` in such a situation instead, but that won't deadlock either. It will instead nest the locks for the thread and make the mutex available for locking by other threads when all nested locks are lifted.

It would be pointless to require such a use to cause a deadlock. Deadlocks are not a valid program state. Threads completely stuck in deadlock are not useful. The standard library is permitted to diagnose a deadlock condition and raise an exception if it would occur (e.g. in a mutex `.lock()` or thread's `.join()`). It may also be considered UB for violation of the forward progress guarantees (I am not sure atm).

Comment: Could use `std::recursive_mutex` for that.

Comment: Should it not just deadlock?

Comment: @define_makefile No. Behavior is undefined: See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex/lock.

Comment: @AykhanHagverdili But that will not deadlock either. It will just nest the locks.

Comment: @define_makefile Btw., causing a deadlock (i.e. completely preventing thread forward progress) also causes undefined behavior anyway.

Comment: @user17732522 No, that will not deadlock. I don't understand why you would want a deadlock here though.

Comment: @user17732522 Are you sure deadlocks cause undefined behavior? Where is that written?

Comment: @AykhanHagverdili The general forward-progress requirements. Eventually the thread must perform some action listed in https://eel.is/c++draft/intro.progress. A complete deadlock does not allow for that.

Comment: @AykhanHagverdili See section "Progress guarantee". Deadlock prevents a thread from terminating. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/memory_model

Comment: @user17732522 It will eventually terminate with `SIGINT` when I click `ctrl+C`. Does that make it defined?

Comment: @AykhanHagverdili When/whether the signal is raised externally and how it will be handled is implemenation-defined. So it is a bit hard to say anything about it. But I read the paragraph I linked above again and I think that the deadlock is probably fine, because it is a call into a standard library function, which I guess can count as eventually performing a call into a standard library function. I do remember however being this discussed as UB somewhere. Either way, there are multiple standard library functions that permit raising exceptions on deadlock detection.